# Missing files from when pulling from git (.NET MVC 4.6)

Tags: c#, git, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2017

I use Entity Framework 6.0 and Data first to generate my models, which I then push to github. But when it's pulled the models generated from EF isn't correctly pulled. I can see, that on github that the remote repository contains the models generated by EF.

I have no idea what files to include here for you guys to get a better understanding, so just tell me and i'll do my best to provide it.

Using git(git bash), .net mvc 4.6, EF 6.0 and Visual Studio Enterprise 2017.

EDIT: Additional information

Comment: is it that the some files are getting missed ? Try expanding the folder structure in VS Solution Manager and selecting "Show All Files" in its menu tab. Maybe the files did got downloaded but aren't included as part of project file

Comment: You might be on to something here. If i open the project through File Explorer i can see that the models actually are there. 
I just can't seem to find the "Show All Files" option?

Comment: In the top of solution explorer, there's a toolstrip on which there is "Show All Files" option

Comment: Wow, that was it. Thanks a lot! Why is it the files aren't automatically included in the project?

Comment: please see details in the answer below, try to repeat whole story (create a fresh EF and check-in) and see if this was actually the case. If it works, you can accept the answer or else provide further insight for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files would have been downloaded by Git, However it's somehow not getting included in the project. Try to expand the EF generated folder, and click the 
[image: Show All Files]

tool strip item to include the model classes back.
Save your project files and then again check-in the project file back to git.

The reason why they weren't included is somehow strange, as the moment you generate your EF model, the files are included in the project. It looks like although the project file was updated by VS, but not saved when you did the check-in (hence an old version without the model went into git)